# Can I use multiple partition external HDD connected to Apple Airport Extreme for Backups from both Mac and Windows PC

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, airport, ntfs

I have a 6TB external drive partitioned into two equal partitions.  One is NTFS and the other is compatible with Time Machine backups.  The drive is then connected to the Airport Extreme via USB.  The Mac can see the Time Machine formatted drive.  Neither the PC or the Mac see the NTFS partition.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Apple support article
https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202807

> The disk **must be formatted as Mac OS Extended, FAT16, or FAT32**.
>
> ...
>
> AirPort base stations **don't support** encrypted formats or disks formatted as APFS, ExFAT, or **NTFS**.

So, unfortunately, it seems like the the answer to your title is no, at least for the Windows / NTFS portion. However, since Time Capsule and AirPort share HFS+ over SMB - any client can write to the disk if you just format all of it using one of the supported file systems (Mac OS Extended, FAT16, or FAT32).

Comment: I went in and enabled SMB1 Client and can now see the MAC OS Extended partition that is intended for Time Machine backups.  So from what you have stated I can change the other partition to a AIrport supported file system but would unlikely be able to write my Acronis backups to it from the Windows 10 PC?

Comment: @Michael It would need Acronis to support SMB - you could surely ask that on superuser.com if Acronis doesn’t list what SMB versions they support if they do. In the past, I recall needing a physical connection for Acronis - but it’s quite possible they can support other connection methods. Just be sure you have a backup of all data on the drive before you erase or change format on either of the sides. I’d hate for you to lose any backups that exist already.